# Rescale a bar chart when y axis range changes in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As a newbie to D3.js, this is a tricky problem that bothers me for a while. I am plotting a series of bars using the SVG `rect` elements, the associated object is (defined outside `d3.csv()` function)

```
var bars = g.selectAll(".bar rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar rect");
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date)})
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(max(d.open, d.close));})
    .attr("width", 2*tickWidth/3)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(min(d.open, d.close)) - y(max(d.open, d.close));})
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.open > d.close ? "red" : "green" ;});
```

However, the data is loaded using `d3.csv()` function from a file. The other settings, such as x, y, etc are rather standard as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219). Now, because I wanted to add one more line on this chart and the range of y axis is changed accordingly. For this, I need to re-map the range for the y axis.

Here comes the problem. First of all, it appears a bit difficult for me to get the `data` from the above bar chart. I used the `data()` method to acquire the data of the above `bars` object (inside `d3.csv()` function while plotting the other line) but it gave me an empty array. Second, I am not sure how I can associated the newly set y range to the bars object without calling again the `data()` method, since each time I fetch the newly mapped y range to the `bar` object, it is plotted again.

I definitely lack a good understanding of the d3's philosophy of separating style and data. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: any chance you could show us your full code?

Comment: I was a bit stupid. It turns out I can use `y.domain()[]` to acquires the range of the current y axis of the chart. This solves the problem without going through the data to determine the minimal and maximal values.